# Way of tracking string concatenated SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

We have a legacy application that builds up lots of strings and runs them on the DB. We want to have a way of tracking back from one of these queries to the area of the code that ran it. The first idea was to manually add GUIDs to all of the queries so we can track them from this point forward but is there an easier way?

Connecting from .NET 3.5 SP1 to SQL Server 2008 R2 machine using the standard library, nothing fancy.

Is there an event on the standard library that maybe we can connect to and use reflection to find out where it was called from to add the same GUID in each time?

Comment: Is there a shared data access layer?

Comment: how does it bnuild up the strings?

Comment: @HLGEM - Sometimes string builder, but mainly just `"..."+ variable + "..."`

Answer (score 1):

If there is a shared data access infrastructure, you can output a full stack trace before each and every database call.

This is not a cheap operation, so consider only doing this in your debug build and environment.

See the [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class.

Comment: Really wanted a way of going from a live environment to a line of code.

Comment: @tgandrews - I don't believe you will find a more direct/simply approach.